Missing child element error on signxml library when signing an xml document
I am trying to have an xml signed, where the signature is the last child element of the root. For this purpose Python's signxml library is used. Previously the cryptography library was used to generate the key and certificate.
Upon running the default signxml configuration.
from lxml import etree
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier

data_to_sign = "<Test/>"
cert = open("cert.pem").read()
key = open("privkey.pem").read()
root = etree.fromstring(data_to_sign)
signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root).signed_xml


I get an error which says a child element is missing.
DocumentInvalid: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Data': 
Missing child element(s). Expected is one of (
{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509IssuerSerial, 
{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509SKI, 
{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509SubjectName, 
{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Certificate, 
{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509CRL, 
##other{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}* )., line 1

How to fix the error?
EDIT: The generation of key and certificate is below.
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa

# Generate our key
key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
)
# Write our key to disk for safe keeping
with open("privkey.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(),
    ))

# Generate a CSR
csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(x509.Name([
    # Provide various details about who we are.
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, "US"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, "California"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, "San Francisco"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, "My Company"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, "mysite.com"),
])).add_extension(
    x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
        # Describe what sites we want this certificate for.
        x509.DNSName("mysite.com"),
        x509.DNSName("www.mysite.com"),
        x509.DNSName("subdomain.mysite.com"),
    ]),
    critical=False,
# Sign the CSR with our private key.
).sign(key, hashes.SHA256())
# Write our CSR out to disk.
with open("cert.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(csr.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))

